# where did NUnit Gui Runner go? version 3.0.1

Tags: nunit

I just upgraded to version 3.0.1 from nunit 2.6.4. It used to have a NUnit Gui Runner, located here:

[image]

After installing 3.0.1 (which I downloaded windows version [from here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download))

I now no longer see the nunit.exe in the installation folder, for example the directory structure is different and appears to be missing many files that were part of the previous installation:

[image]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The NUnit team decided to make the GUI a separate product and will be releasing it separately. It is being rewritten from the ground up for NUnit 3, but hasn't been released yet. Development is happening on the GitHub page at https://github.com/nunit/nunit-gui if you want to get involved or track the progress. Initial releases will be out soon.

**Update** - There have been several preview releases of the new NUnit GUI that can be found at https://github.com/nunit/nunit-gui/releases. The previews are not recommended for production use, but they work and can be used.

Comment: So, how the heck are you supposed to run tests??  With the console client?  Who would ever want to use that instead of the GUI client?  FYI, there's still no version of the GUI at the link you provided that is ready to use "out of the box" -- e.g. with an MSI.

Comment: @rory.ap, actually, most people use the Visual Studio adapter and run/debug their tests directly in Visual Studio. Other people use Resharper, TestDriven.NET, NCrunch or many of the other GUI based runners that integrate with their IDE. There are also plugins for MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently trying to get things working using VS "Test" menu "Test Explorer".

Comment: @rory.ap, also, despite your assertion, many developers do use the command line tools these day and there hasn't been much interest in helping out with the GUI runner, so it is moving slowly. We attribute that to the fact that most users have moved on to other runners, but that may be wrong. Feel free to chip in and help out :)

Comment: @rory.ap, install the NUnit 3 adapter and your tests should show up. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d

Comment: Okay, this is *wayyy* better than the 2.x GUI of yore!  Thanks!

Comment: The problem with the VS adapter is that for the project I'm working on at the moment it just seems to stall/hang on certain tests. This is why the NUnit GUI is a handy fallback for when the R# test runner plays up (e.g., I'm currently trying to debug something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124109/how-can-i-get-reason-of-resharpers-aborted-tests). The old NUnit GUI was simple, fast, lightweight, and unencumbered by all the bloat of Visual Studio so if you have unreliable tests for whatever reason it can be a good option.

Comment: Btw, if you do want to run the NUnit 3 GUI runner, it's pretty easy to set up. Just clone the repo and run `build.ps1`. This will build the project and spit _nunit-gui.exe_ out in _.\bin\Release_. It seems to work pretty well so far.

Comment: Not working for me:
Executing task: Build

  nunit.uikit -> I:\misc\nunit\nunit-gui-master\bin\Release\nunit.uikit.dll
Views\AddinPages\ExtensionNodeView.cs(92,34): error CS1056: Unexpected character '$' [I:\misc\nunit\nunit-gui-master\sr
c\nunit-gui\nunit-gui.csproj]
  mock-assembly -> I:\misc\nunit\nunit-gui-master\bin\Release\mock-assembly.dll
An error occured when executing task 'Build'.
Error: MSBuild: Process returned an error (exit code 1).

Comment: In my experience, the .zip files available at https://github.com/TestCentric/experimental-nunit-gui/releases now contain the ready-to-run .exe.

Comment: Does anyone know if the current 0.6 NUnit GUI has been abandoned or is the production on it halted?

Comment: @JoeC Right now the last commit on the project is from Jul 19, a few days ago, so at least there is some development. Most likely still alpha quality, but evolving. And yet still much worse than NUnit 2.6.4.

Comment: The above link is obsolete. The GUI has moved to the a new repository: https://github.com/TestCentric/testcentric-gui/releases

Comment: Tests which require UI thread can cause the Visual Studio hang if executed using the test adapter.  (At least in vs2017. Not sure about VS2019).

Answer (score 4):

The "final" release is here, you can find it at: https://github.com/TestCentric/testcentric-gui/releases

Comment: Confirmed as of 4/1/2021 to still be the best URL

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming to this page, looking  where to find the  NUnit Gui, please note that on http://nunit.org/?p=download you can get version 2.6.4, which does contain the Gui.

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in the comments, a lot has changed since, and you should no longer use the 2.x version tools, rather use the new TestCentric UI found at https://github.com/TestCentric/testcentric-gui/releases

Comment: 2.6.4 still contains a GUI, but people should be aware that 2.6.4 will not run tests written with 3.x

Comment: @RobProuse Yes, it does. As long as you don't use any features that were not available in 2.6.4.

Comment: @kent-anderson it may seem to work, but you are playing with fire. You may get false positives, missed tests, etc. For anything but the simplest tests, I would highly recommend not trying to run NUnit 3 tests in the old GUI runner.

Comment: As pointed out in the other comment, the current download location is a remake and given a new name:
https://github.com/TestCentric/testcentric-gui/releases